# Python Iterating over rrule from dateutil

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-dateutil

I am trying to iterate a function over the list returned from rrule and keep getting "object has no attribute '**getitem**'" message. Does that mean I first have to "parse" results from rrule to be able to use them for iteration?

Example code

```
for smoketest in rrule.rrule(rrule.HOURLY, dtstart=startD, until=endD):
  print smoketest
  dateID = smoketest[0:10]
  hourID = smoketest[11:13]
```

Exact error is TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute '**getitem**'.

Sorry if this sounds kind of dumb, This is my first in programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`smoketest` is a `datetime.datetime` object, not a string. What you see in `print` is its string representation. `datetime.datetime` object offers much more.

Do you need the `smoketest` as date string and as time string? Use the [`strftime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) method:

```
for smoketest in rrule.rrule(rrule.HOURLY, dtstart=startD, until=endD):
    dateID = smoketest.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    hourID = smoketest.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: God I feel dumb :) Thanks a bunch (again eumiro!). dateID is exactly like yours, hourID is only Hours. Thought I can extract it the other way around. Will remember this for future works.

Comment: @panta - if `hourID` is only hours, use `smoketest.strftime('%H')`. If you need it as an integer, use `smoketest.hour`.